# MS Access Control Source DLookUp

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I haven't been able to make a DLookUp function work in an Access report. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The report is getting its dataset from a query called Aggregate Query. This query builds a dataset from 20 related tables using CustomerID as the primary key in one table and as a foreign key in the other 19. CustomerID is specified by an open Form with the desired customer's record displayed, including the CustomerID field.

This means Aggregate Query has several rows for one specific CustomerID. One field, Needs Notes, will have the same content on every row. What I'm having trouble with is getting only one of these rows displayed in the subreport, and subsequently on the parent report.

If there are six rows, say, in Aggregate Query, then the same Needs Notes field is repeated six times. I want it to appear only once in the subreport.

I couldn't choose only the first row from Aggregate Query. If this can be done that'd be great. I don't know.

So I created another query, Need-notes Only Query, which always gives me only one row every time. So far so good. Now I want the contents of the Needs Notes field to appear all by itself in the subreport. To do this I selected the text box and entered the following into the Control Source parameter:

```
=DLookUp("[Needs-notes Only Query]![Needs Notes]","Needs-notes Only Query")
```

No dice. I get six rows saying #Error.

Is there a way I can get just one row of the Needs Notes field into my report?

Comment: Can you share that _Needs-notes Only Query_? Likely that contains something that's invalid for a `DLookUp`.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might be the "missing" square brackets around the domain. But, in fact, I get an error message about incorrect syntax after I insert them. That's not it.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant. The subform consists of four sections with content: Page Header (where I put the report's title); Page Header (where I have a text books with an expression that uses field content to create a paragraph-formatted narrative); Group Header (which is a continuation of the narrative because the previous expression was more than 1024 characters); and Detail (which is where the problematic text box resides). Might this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Split field and table names:

```
=DLookUp("[Needs Notes]","[Needs-notes Only Query]")
```

Comment: Thought that was it too at first, but I couldn't reproduce the error. I don't think this fixes it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: The query name needs brackets when spaces are involved.

Comment: As said, I thought it did, but in my setup and in a `DLookUp`, it doesn't. I can't get an error when using a query name with spaces and no brackets.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I recall some trouble, but I didn't check. Let's see the outcome.